Syncing external API data to firebase
I have a firebase app that i need to sync with an external API source for a small calendar project for my company.
I have a firestore database that keeps all my data, but recently we started using another service that has an API i need to sync with.
So, my thought has been to create a firebase cloud function that gets all my events from firestore, then fetches all events from the external API. Now i have all the data needed. I would run this function on mount. We have 3-5 users, so i'm not focusing very much on scalability here..
But, i want firestore to be the source of truth for my app, so in this cloud function, i need to check for changes like so:

If data from API is different from firestore -> update data in firestore.
If data from API does not exist in firestore -> create document in
firestore.
If status field (called subprojectStatus in firestore) from API contains string a, b, c or d -> Remove
document from firestore

This is my code so far, its a little flawed, but i'm having trouble combining the three features i need from the list above into a function that actually does what i need.
edit: What i need help with is not fetching or settings, i need help with the function itself.
I would really appreciate a more detailed answer as i'm learning more and more as i work.
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore, Timestamp} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const axios = require("axios");

initializeApp();

exports.syncWithRentman = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const rentmanData = await get("https://api.rentman.net/subprojects", 100, 0);

  const db = getFirestore();
  const ref = db.collection("development");
  const doc = await ref.get();
  const result = [];
  const allowedStatusFromAPI = [
    "/statuses/1",
    // "/statuses/2",
    "/statuses/3",
    "/statuses/4",
    "/statuses/5",
    // "/statuses/6",
    // "/statuses/7",
    "/statuses/8",
  ];

  doc.forEach(doc => {
    result.push(doc.data());
    console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
  });

  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log("No such document!");
  } else {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

    // console.log(results);
    doc.forEach(doc => {
      result.push(doc.data());
      console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
    });
  }
  const results = rentmanData.data.filter(
      ({
        id: id2,
        planperiod_start: start2,
        planperiod_end: end2,
        status: subprojectStatus2,
      }) => {
        if (result.some(i => i.id !== id2)) {
          return true;
        }
        return result.some(
            ({
              id: id1,
              start: start1,
              end: end1,
              subprojectStatus: subprojectStatus1,
            }) => {
              const start1Edit = new Timestamp(
                  start1._seconds,
                  start1._nanoseconds,
              );
              const end1Edit = new Timestamp(end1._seconds, end1._nanoseconds);
              const tempIdFromString = Number(id1);
              return (
                id2 === tempIdFromString &&
            (new Date(start2).toISOString() !==
              start1Edit.toDate().toISOString() ||
              new Date(end2).toISOString() !==
                end1Edit.toDate().toISOString() ||
              subprojectStatus2 !== subprojectStatus1)
              );
            },
        );
      },
  );


  // The return statement is debugging the data: afterFIlter is the one i was aiming for to deliver the updated data.
  return {
    fromFirebase: result,
    fromRentman: rentmanData,
    afterFilter: results,
  };
});

The data objects look like this:
const rentmanData = [
            {
                "custom": {
                    "custom_8": true
                },
                "id": 236,
                "created": "2023-02-09T14:42:22+01:00",
                "modified": "2023-02-09T14:42:22+01:00",
                "creator": "/crew/33",
                "displayname": "Sommerhytta 2023",
                "project": "/projects/195",
                "order": 1,
                "name": "Sommerhytta 2023",
                "status": "/statuses/8",
                "is_template": true,
                "location": null,
                "loc_contact": null,
                "insurance_rate": 0,
                "discount_rental": 0,
                "discount_sale": 0,
                "discount_crew": 0,
                "discount_transport": 0,
                "discount_additional_costs": 0,
                "discount_subproject": 0,
                "discount_fixed": false,
                "discount_fixed_amount": 0,
                "fixed_price": false,
                "in_planning": true,
                "in_financial": true,
                "asset_location_from": "/stocklocations/1",
                "already_invoiced": 0,
                "planperiod_start": "1980-04-03T16:00:00+01:00",
                "planperiod_end": "1980-07-10T00:00:00+02:00",
                "volume": 0,
                "weight": 0,
                "power": 0,
                "current": 0,
                "purchasecosts": 0,
                "equipment_period_from": "1980-04-03T16:00:00+01:00",
                "equipment_period_to": "1980-07-10T00:00:00+02:00",
                "updateHash": "ca7a99bc87fd932a97a05ea038f47622"
            },

const result = [
         {
                "color": "#eb5930",
                "subprojectStatus": "/statuses/6",
                "resource": [
                    4
                ],
                "editable": true,
                "start": {
                    "_seconds": 1691589600,
                    "_nanoseconds": 0
                },
                "description": "Hovedpakke",
                "title": "Hovedpakke",
                "allDay": true,
                "busy": false,
                "end": {
                    "_seconds": 1697752800,
                    "_nanoseconds": 0
                },
                "visibleInCalendar": true,
                "id": 241,
                "status": "busy",
                "createdAt": {
                    "_seconds": 1711995708,
                    "_nanoseconds": 278000000
                }
            },
        ]

